# accessing phonegap database in android native

Tags: cordova

I m new to phone gap platform.
I'm facing a issue in accessing the phone gap db in android native code.

In one of the application I want to do a synch mechanism
For every 10 minutes the alarm broadcast receiver will wake up the class and start a background service. In that service we are accessing the phone gap db . if in case the db is being used by the JavaScript code, n I start to fetch the record from the same db , I'm getting an exception SQL ITE database locked exception .. Please help me in sorting out this problem.

Thanks.